# Why in read-from-string (+ 4 5 6) equals 9?

Tags: common-lisp

Why read-from-string does give nonsense?

```
CL-USER> (read-from-string "(+ 4 5 6)")
(+ 4 5 6)
9
CL-USER> (+ 4 5 6)
15
CL-USER> (eval (read-from-string "(+ 4 5 6)"))
15
CL-USER>
```

Comment: `read-from-string` doesn't evaluate the list. The second value is the character position the object ends at in the string.

Answer (score 6):

From [CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_fro.htm)>

> The secondary value, `position`, is the index of the first character in the bounded string that was not read. The position may depend upon the value of `preserve-whitespace`. If the entire string was read, the position returned is either the length of the string or one greater than the length of the string.

`9` is the length of the string `"(+ 4 5 6)"`.

This is useful if there are multiple objects in the string. You can use this returned position as the `:start` value in the next call.

Answer (score 1):

Common Lisp functions can return more than one value. That's a feature, which is not common for programming languages. The language designers thought that returning multiple values is possibly more efficient than returning a list or vector of the results.

The *READ EVAL PRINT LOOP* prints all results, one after the other.

We can also get the result values in a program and print them one by one:

```
CL-USER > (progn
            (multiple-value-call
                (lambda (&rest args)
                  (loop for i from 0 and arg in args
                        do (format t "~%Argument ~a: ~s" i arg)))
              (read-from-string "(+ 4 5 6)"))
            (values))

Argument 0: (+ 4 5 6)
Argument 1: 9
```

`MULTIPLE-VALUE-CALL` calls a functions. The arguments for the function are the return values of a function call. Here the lambda function will be called with arguments, which were the return values of the `READ-FROM-STRING` function call.

Thus you will need to look at the documentation or the source code, what result values (not just one!) a function may return.

Barmar pointed you to the documentation for each standard Common Lisp identifier, the **Common Lisp HyperSpec**. The HyperSpec documents each return value of functions, macros and special forms.